# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lxml

I was trying to use aws lambda functions. I needed to use lxml python module.

when I try to import:

```
from lxml import html

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    return 'okay'
```

aws shows some errors. Here:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/var/task/lxml/__init__.py)",
 "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
 "requestId": "426b7f93-d703-4d7d-9bda-86cbfdf85fe2",
 "stackTrace": []
}
```

When I was trying to use the 'html' from lxml on local PC. The code was working on python 3.10 version only. It worked with conda environment and local PC on python-3.10 only.

1. I tried to install the updated lxml module.
2. Tried 3.10 python version on AWS Lambda
3. Installing the lxml on Docker Ubuntu. then upload the .zip
4. Using the module as layer on AWS.

Nothing works. What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: lambda is not based on `Docker Ubuntu`, but on Amazon Linux.

Comment: I have installed the requests module. That worked correctly. Maybe the packages layer is not an issue.

Yes, I know Amazon is running on Linux. But I am unable to install the module on my mac which works on lambda too.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `lxml` is an OS-dependent library. If you install it using your macbook or ubuntu, you will get binaries that are going to be incompatible with the OS used inside the Lambda runtime which is (Amazon Linux 2).

To solve this, you will have to generate binaries that are compatible with Amazon Linux 2.

- You can either use a pre-built packaging Docker image like `lambci/lambda` ([Check here](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/))
- Create your own custom Dockerfile that will copy the `requirements.txt` file inside the Amazon Linux-based container
  and run the `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You can then copy the python packages produced by the Docker container into the host machine (Your PC or the CI/CD agent) and zip it with your code to Lambda.  You can take a look at this example for [Python 3.11](https://dev.to/gaborschulz/running-python-311-on-aws-lambda-1i7p).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate the first option please?

Comment: @SorowerHossan If your application is compatible with python 3.8, I'd recommend using the pre-built packaging Docker images built by lambci, this basically provides a built lambda-like environments where you can install your dependencies during build time. To learn more about this process, you can read this article: https://rajesh-r6r.medium.com/an-ultimate-guide-developing-lambda-functions-locally-for-aws-lambda-16d4a40d3ba4